# Knockout nested sortable sourceParent.splice is not a function

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0, knockout-sortable, knockout-templating

Here I'm working on code that uses Knockout sortable. It should display nested sortables 3+ levels in depth.

The data are passed to the template, but some elements return to their original position after being dropped (e.g. **A,B elements on uppermost level**).

How should I configure the nested sortable so that the uppermost level can be also used without the error?

**ERROR:**

> knockout-sortable.js:244 Uncaught TypeError: sourceParent.splice is not a function
>
> or
>
> knockout-sortable.js:252 Uncaught TypeError: targetParent.splice is not a function

[JSFiddle - Similar working example](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Lqttf/)

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.children = ko.observable([{
    "name": "A",
    "children": [{
      "name": "A1",
      "children": [{
        "name": "A11"
      }, {
        "name": "A12"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "A2"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "B",
    "children": [{
      "name": "B1"
    }, {
      "name": "B2"
    }]
  }]);
}
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```css
ul {
  border: solid 1px green;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin:0px;
}
li {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable/master/build/knockout-sortable.js"></script>

<script id="nodeTmpl" type="text/html">
  <li>
    <!-- ko if: $data.name -->
    <a href="#" data-bind="text: $data.name"></a>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: $data.children -->
    <ul data-bind="sortable: { template: 'nodeTmpl', data: $data.children }"></ul>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </li>
</script>

<ul data-bind="sortable: { template: 'nodeTmpl', data: $root.children }"></ul>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is solved by making changes to lines `<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'nodeTmpl', data: $root }"></ul>` and I removed `$data` from some references, because it was causing the error.

```js
var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.children = [{
    "name": "A",
    "children": [{
      "name": "A1",
      "children": [{
        "name": "A11",
      }, {
        "name": "A12",
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "A2",
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "B",
    "children": [{
      "name": "B1",
    }, {
      "name": "B2",
    }]
  }]
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.2.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable/master/build/knockout-sortable.js"></script>

<script id="nodeTmpl" type="text/html">
  <li>
    <!-- ko if: $data.name -->
    <a href="#" data-bind="text: name"></a>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: $data.children -->
    <ul data-bind="sortable: { template: 'nodeTmpl', data: children }"></ul>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </li>
</script>

<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'nodeTmpl', data: $root }"></ul>
```

Comment: The provided snippet still doesn't work. While the error has disappeared, dragging makes elements either not move or disappear entirely. I've posted an answer that solves these issues. Also, removing the `$data` blocks was unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by [Peter Gerhat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5185570/peter-gerhat) is incorrect.
The problem is the fact that an [observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) of an array was used, rather than an [observableArray](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html).

The error states that `sourceParent` (which is the collection on the viewmodel from which the element is being dragged), does not have a `splice` function. Which is correct, an observable does not have a `splice` function, while an `array` or an `observableArray` does. The same applies to `targetParent` (which is the collection on the viewmodel to which the element is being dragged).

To make the initial sample work, all that needs to be done is change `observable` to `observableArray`.

However, as you will notice in the original sample and the solution provided by [Peter Gerhat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5185570/peter-gerhat), even though no error is thrown, it still doesn't really work as it should. You'll notice that while you're dragging elements either don't move at all, or disappear.

The solution here is to turn each `array` into an `observableArray`, so that they can be updated by the `sortable`-binding.

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.children = ko.observableArray([{
    "name": "A",
    "children": ko.observableArray([{
      "name": "A1",
      "children": ko.observableArray([{
        "name": "A11"
      }, {
        "name": "A12"
      }])
    }, {
      "name": "A2"
    }])
  }, {
    "name": "B",
    "children": ko.observableArray([{
      "name": "B1"
    }, {
      "name": "B2"
    }])
  }]);
}
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```css
ul {
  border: solid 1px green;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable/master/build/knockout-sortable.js"></script>

<script id="nodeTmpl" type="text/html">
  <li>
    <!-- ko if: $data.name -->
    <a href="#" data-bind="text: $data.name"></a>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: $data.children -->
    <ul data-bind="sortable: { template: 'nodeTmpl', data: $data.children }"></ul>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </li>
</script>

<ul data-bind="sortable: { template: 'nodeTmpl', data: $root.children }"></ul>
```